# Backbone Collection - Caching Rendered Collections

Tags: jquery, caching, backbone.js, view, filtering

I'm attempting to optimize rendering of a searchable Backbone Collection that is rendered on the page.  My goal is to display cached searches to the user as fast as possible so that it prevents noticible 'lag' while they are typing.

While my current solution uses setTimout to asynchrousuly display rendered items in the view, it becomes troublesome to render the full collection again once the user erases all of the text in the search box (i.e., render 600+ items).

So for example, my initial render on page load is the following:

```
render: function(collection) {
    this.el_html = [];

    this.$el.html('');
    collection = collection || this.collection;

    if (collection.length > 0) {
        (function(that) {
            collection.each(function(item) {
                that.renderItemHtml(item);
            });
        })(this);

        this.$el.html(this.el_html);
    } else {
        this.$el.html($('#noItemsTemplate').html());
    }

    return this;
},
```

And instead of appending an item to the current view (for optimizations), I just grab the html in my renderItemHtml:

```
 renderItemHtml: function(item) {
    var itemView = new this.itemView({
        model: item
    });
    this.el_html.push(itemView.render().el);
},
```

After my views are drawn and the user performs a search, I use the following render instead (to avoid the previously aforementioned UI lag):

```
renderFiltered: function(collection) {
    var numActiveItems = 0,
        totalItems = 0,
        numItemsDisplayed = 0;

    collection = collection || this.collection;
    collection.comparator = 'name';
    collection.sort();

    //get the total number of active items
    numActiveItems = this.collection.where({
        active: true
    }).length;
    totalItems = numActiveItems;
    numItemsDisplayed = collection.toArray().length;
    if (collection.length == this.collection.length) {
        return this;
    }
    this.$el.html('');
    if (numItemsDisplayed < totalItems) {
        this.$el.append('<div>Displaying ' + numItemsDisplayed + ' out of ' + totalItems + '</div>');
    }

    if (collection.length > 0) {
        this.searchNum++;
        this.renderItems(collection.models, 0, this.searchNum);
    }
}
```

And each of these views are asynchronously added like so:

```
renderItem: function(item) {
    var itemView = new this.itemView({
        model: item
    });

    this.$el.append(itemView.render().el);
},
```

Now, the performance hit is not TOO bad when performing searches because those collections only have a length of 400 max on average.  But my concern is when rendereing larger collections.

So my question:  Is it possible to cache the rendered view's $el and when you are to display results for that search a second time through, set the view's $el to the cached element?  I've successfully done this by caching the HTML, but not the events attached to each of the models that are supposed to be rendered in the collection.

When I render the cached collection using something like:

```
this.$el.replaceWith(this.cache[search_query].el);
```

the resulting html content of this.$el does not display what was stored in the cached element, but the previously rendered list...even though the cached element seems to have all of the outerHTML that it originally had and even the events (when viewing through debugger).

However, the following renders perfectly, but the individual item views events are missing:

```
this.$el.append(this.cache[search_query].el);
```

Also, this.delegateEvents() seems to only target the current view (i.e., my library view and not the individual items).

Is there any method that you may recommend for caching rendered filtered elements and re-rendering them with events still in place?

Please let me know if you need any more code/info.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Oops!  Edited post (see question at end of post)